# Select certain elements from a dataframe column with a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with one column containing python lists. How can I access certain elements of that list, e.g. the first and second only:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]})
```

```
           a
0  [a, b, c]
1  [e, f, g]
```

Desired output:

```
        a
0  [a, b]
1  [e, f]
```

I was looking into `.apply()`, but I cannot find the appropriate function to apply to the list to get out the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using `.apply()` and `lambda`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]})

df['a'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: row[0][:2],
    axis=1
)

print(df)
```

2. Using list comprehension

```
df.a = [x[:2] for x in df.a]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
        a
0  [a, b]
1  [e, f]
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
import pandas as pd
df['a'] = df['a'].str[:2]
```

Result will be as follows:

```
    a
0   ['a', 'b']
1   ['e', 'f']
```